# Canonicalise XML file using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-4.0, c14n

Is there an inbuilt mechanism within PowerShell (or within .NET that can be used by PowerShell) that will allow me to canonicalise an XML file (see step 2 below)?

The canonicalisation must be based on the W3C rules described at https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments but there must be a way to do this within .NET without having to manually implement these rules.

My use case is the following:

1. Create DOM representation of the XML file
2. Create canonicalised representation of the DOM
3. Generate digital signature of the canonicalised representation using SHA-256.
4. Encode the binary signature into base64 encoded string
5. Place signature string in the SOAP message

Comment: [XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-overview-wpf)?

Comment: @iRon I don't understand the question. Are you saying that using XAML can help in this case? And if so, how can it help?